# How can I share a Visual Studio project across computers easily?

Tags: visual-studio, project, share

I own two computers at two different houses. I want to be able to work on a Visual Studio project on both of these computers easily.

Currently I'm mailing the project from one computer to the other, or using Dropbox. Very inconvenient.

What's the easiest way to share the project more conveniently?

Btw, I'm using the free Visual Studio Community 2013 edition, and I'm looking for a free option.

Comment: Use distributed source control.  Git combined with GitHub, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is using version controlling system like Git

Answer (score 0):

Use [Visual Studio Online](http://visualstudioonline.com) to manage your Project, it is free for up to 5 users and you can use Git as your version control. Then you just create a new Project and add your code. AFter this it is easy to commit and sync your work on both computers.

Answer (score -1):

Either use the VS community version; there is also a cloud version, or it could be shared with dropbox or onedrive and many others.